# Php script, query ran from value thats passed in

Tags: php, variables

I am pretty new at php, quick note this is an android application that i am calling this script, I am not having the users make up the script lol. There is a series of checkboxs and when they check off certain ones it appends a script to the string builder. i am trying to run a query based on the value of a variable that is being passed in. Usually i do something like this,

```
   mssql_query("UPDATE Userdata SET BrowseScript = '".$_REQUEST['sqlscript']."' 
WHERE Userdata.Username = '".$_REQUEST['Username']."'");
```

and where it says .`$_REQUEST['']` I can grab values that i pass in.

But this time the `.$_REQUEST['']` is the whole script, so i want something like this

```
mssql_query($_REQUEST['sqlscript']);
```

and thats it i want it to run the query thats in that value, The query is correct, but it just will not return any value, I think i may have some type of syntax error or something, like i said i am new to php. Thanks for any help. Also I am not posting the whole code because everything is running ok, i just cant get that query to run. so all i need assistance with is the mssql_query part thanks again.

Comment: make sanity check on the input before insert to db , see sql injection in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is **huge security flaw in what you are doing**. You should always sanitalize and escape the variables you use in your queries for example using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or prepared statements.

Since you are importing whole script for your query, it could be that quotes are not escaped. You need to put these functions like this before your variables:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['your_var']);
```

Using `$_REQUEST` in itself instead of proper `$_GET` or `$_POST` is vulnerable.

Comment: sooo, can you show me how my ms_query line would look? and that says mysql

Comment: @user516883: Just prepend `mysql_real_escpae_string` function before your query variables eg ` mssql_query("UPDATE Userdata SET BrowseScript = '".mysql_real_escpae_string($_REQUEST['sqlscript'])."' 
WHERE Userdata.Username = '".mysql_real_escpae_string($_REQUEST['Username'])."'");`

Comment: I dont not follow? I am not running the query like that the query is a vlalue that is being passed through

Answer (score 0):

**For all that's holy, do not do this!**

You do *not* just use request parameters and put them in SQL queries. You at the very least use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (or whatever the MSSQL equivalent is, never used it). And you most certainly don't accept whole queries in the request and execute them sight unseen.

You're opening huge gaping security holes. Especially if you're new, stop that now before it becomes a habit!

```
example.com/foo.php?sqlscript=DROP TABLE users
```

Minimum required lecture: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Tell your script to output the contents of $_REQUEST['sqlscript']

   echo $REQUEST['sqlscript'];
2. Check that the output is correct.  You might well find that there are some parsing errors, or just that your script is incomplete.  Check for quotes (") and make sure the query is valid.
3. Also, you should **never** run a script from a request.  Imagine if someone browsed to your site and typed

   youtsite.com?sqlscript='drop * from tables';

Your entire database would be wiped.

Comment: its an android app and no website involved, and the user is not providing the sql script there is a series of checkboxs and as they click the stringbuilder creates the sql script that is ran. plese help with full ms_sql code, thanks!

Comment: can you output the value of echo $REQUEST['sqlscript'];

Comment: Here is how i get data back from all my php script, other than what i am about to post now, I dont know.  while($e=mssql_fetch_assoc($q))
            $output[]=$e;
    print(json_encode($output));
    mssql_close();